# ESAPI 2.2.3.1 throwing org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException when using httpUtilities

Tags: java, java-7, java-ee-7, owasp, esapi

I'm using ESAPI 2.2.3.1 and trying to run this code.

```
ESAPI.httpUtilities().setCurrentHTTP(request, response);
ESAPI.httpUtilities().sendRedirect(appURL);
ESAPI.httpUtilities().clearCurrent();
```

I changed the App Name and Validator.Redirect in ESAPI.properties.

When I invoke the code I got the exceptions below, what I am missing to make this work?

> ESAPI: Attempting to load ESAPI.properties via the classpath.
> ESAPI: SUCCESSFULLY LOADED ESAPI.properties via the CLASSPATH from '.esapi/' using current thread >context class loader!
> ESAPI: Attempting to load validation.properties via the classpath.
> ESAPI: SUCCESSFULLY LOADED validation.properties via the CLASSPATH from '.esapi/' using current >thread context class loader!
> **>org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException >HTTPUtilities class (org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultHTTPUtilities) CTOR threw exception.**

Additional Information:
Using JDK 1.7 and Tomcat 8.5

Answer (score 1):

To know for sure, I'd need to see your full exception stack trace as somewhere in the stack, we should see a "Caused by:" referring to the actual culprit. But since you did not show that (feel free to add it if my speculation is incorrect), if I were to hazard a guess, my guess would be that you are using the *old* setting for `ESAPI.Logger` in your **ESAPI.properties** file. The ESAPI logger packages were reorganized (back in 2.2.1.0 I think) when support for SLF4J was added. The old values will no longer work as those classes no longer exist in ESAPI and will result in a `ClassNotFoundException` (or in rare occasions, a `NullPointerException`). See the **2.2.3.0** release notes under the section "Old News -- Important Logging Changes" for details on this. (Unfortunately, I seemed to have forgotten to carry that warning to the 2.2.3.1 release notes, so if that is the cause of your problems, my apologies. Writing the release notes is a manual and very tedious process so sometimes things fall through the cracks.)